# How can I open my protected folders from another users account in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares

We have a network with a server running Windows Server 2003 and the workstations running XP Pro.  I am a domain admin but I'm not local admin on all the workstations.  I have a folder on  the server for my files so I can access it from any workstation and it is restricted to my account.  There are times when I have to jump on other peoples workstations temporarily.  Is there any way for me to access my restricted folder without having to log them off and log in as myself?  Ideally it would popup a prompt and I could enter my password.

I've tried running an elevated instance of Windows Explorer but it denies me telling my I don't have permission, probably because my account is not a local admin.

Answer (score 2):

Share the folder on your server machine. Then you can access this share at a workstation machine by mapping a new drive. Enter the server's address + share and then - that's the point - check the checkbox for login as another user! Now you can enter your credentials from the server's machine (resp. active directory, if available).
Give attention, that the shared folder has the correct permission for your credentials (i.e. full control).

Comment: So I have to map the folder as a new drive on each workstation I'm at?

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe it should also be possible to enter the server-address+sharename in the address bar of the windows explorer (not IE).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are an admin of the server, from the user's workstation, open a run prompt and enter \\SERVERNAME\c$.

If the currently logged in user does not have access to the admin share, Windows will prompt you for your username and credentials. (you may need to enter DOMAIN/username in order to validate)

Once in c$, you should be able to browse to the files you are looking for.

But remember, once you provide your credentials to the server, the currently logged in user will keep full access to the server's files until they log off/back on, or you manually "Disconnect Network Drive..." from the tools menu in Explorer.

Comment: You should not use the system (!) share for access at other workstations. Furthermore give attention, which drive (c$, d$, ...) you want to access, if you follow this steps.

Additional you can check the saved credentials on the workstation to be sure, that your data is not saved after reconnect.
Just press Windowskey+r and enter: "rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr". There you can all saved credentials on the current machine.

Comment: What is objectionable about using the system share if you remove the connection afterwards? I was assuming that the information Matt was looking for was on the C drive, though I guess I should have specifically stated that he could replace c$ with the drive letter that the data resides on.

Comment: The fact, that the workstation user have full control to the system's share, if you forget to remove the connection afterwards! ;) 

But please see my comment just as note, not as no-go!